# Spring Boot is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to create shaded jar for my spring project with bellow pom.xml, which runs fine in IDE but when I run `mvn clean package` and execute the jar with  `java -jar .\flink-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-test.jar` I am getting:

> Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to
> following reasons:
>
> - Spring Boot [0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train
> - Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.6.x, 2.7.x] .

I checked spring cloud compability matrix where spring cloud 2021.0.x is compatible with spring boot 2.6.x.

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>flink</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>flink</name>
<description>flink</description>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.8</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>test</shadedClassifierName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Project currently contain only single Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies

Comment: What I should check there @khmarbaise?

Answer (score 3):

Shading the jar means that the version compatibility that checks the manifest is broken. Set `spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false`

Comment: Yes, spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false resolve the issue, but why shading the jar broke this check. It work fine on spring boot 2.7.0.

Comment: It reads a file in the jar for the spring boot version. It gets overridden by some other jar